# OpenCV and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, opencv, pattern-recognition

I am looking at pattern recognition in images and video and have thought that C++ is the way to go (for high performance/real-time applications). I want to use the OpenCV libraries in Xcode when I build a C++ application (command-line tool)

I am running Xcode 3.2 and have just followed the steps at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port up to "This probably breaks something in TIFF export, but the build at least completes" in the section "Building using the new CMake build system". I have had no errors.

How do I proceed if I want to use the libraries in Xcode now or do I need to do something else? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Max.

Comment: No clue, but had you tried to post this question in the OpenCV forum? I think you'd have more feedback there than here :) http://groups.yahoo.com/subscribe/OpenCV

Comment: I second the OpenCV forum. Every time I've had an OpenCV question, it got answered to my satisfaction within a couple of hours.

Comment: If you're still there, I just started working with OpenCV a few days ago. After you've compiled you just need to link to the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically its a matter of finding the produced library and dropping it into your xcode project. You can either copy the library into your project or just have a reference to it.

There is a section in the ["Xcode Project Management Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/130-Files_in_Projects/project_files.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002666-SW4) document that explains how to link libraries and frameworks into your application.

The "Linking" section of ["Xcode Build System Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/500-Linking/bs_linking.html) might be a good read.