# OpenCV with Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm not able to compile my code in XCode. It is giving me errors. Anybody knows proper steps to install OpenCV and then compile?

Comment: Question is very vague - need specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Which plattform are you developing for? iOS or OS X?

For iOS take a look at this blog post: http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/ There is even a sample project.

If you're trying to use OpenCV for a desktop application you need to compile OpenCV and then import it into your Xcode project >> [Compile OpenCV (2.3.1+) for OS X Lion / Mountain Lion with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552839/compile-opencv-2-3-1-for-os-x-lion-10-7-2-with-xcode/8559953#8559953)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [OpenCV.framework](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PrivateFramework) directly from WillowGarage.

It's based on the older C-based interfaces for OpenCV.

If you're dead set on using the latest OpenCV, with its C++ interfaces, make sure you're compiling all of your sources with .mm extension so that the compiler knows you're working in Objective-C++ mode.

If your project is C++-only, you should expand on what's failing in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SOF which deals with OpenCV and Iphone. Have a look at it?

[iPhone and OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

Another useful SOF to check out:

[OpenCV and Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834189/opencv-and-xcode)