# Linking OpenCV static libraries in Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv, build, static-libraries

(I am new at pretty much everything that I will discuss here... apologies if the question is very basic) - I used Xcode to write some C++ code using OpenCV (dynamic libraries). The algorithm runs smoothly and I created an executable file that also works. However, it only works in my computer.

I understand that I need to use static libraries instead of dynamic libraries. I have done some research and found how to do this here: http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/ and here: http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/opencv-snow-leopard/.

I have followed the steps and, although I had to make a couple of changes, I was able to build ".a" files such as "libopencv_highgui.a".

My code, however, doesn't work anymore when I replace the libraries. I get 200+ errors. This is one of them:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_gzputs", referenced from:
>         __ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)

I have searched for this question here but this is the closest I could find: [Linking OpenCV libraries in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805202/linking-opencv-libraries-in-xcode) (not exactly the same question).

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `.a` files from `$OPENCV_BUILD_PATH/3rdparty/lib/`.

The `_gzputs` from your question belongs to `libzlib.a`

---

To link with OpenCV static libraries you also need to add all OpenCV's dependencies to you application. The most of these dependencies comes from the opencv_highui module and the list of dependencies is dependent from your build configuration so I can't tell you the full list. But you can find it yourself: open the `CMakeCache.txt` from your OpenCV build directory with any text editor and search for `opencv_highgui_LIB_DEPENDS` line. You need all items from that line except the word `general`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. Now I only get 25% of the errors. I think I still need to do something about the libopencv_highgui.a: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _cvInitSystem in libopencv_highgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
      -[CVWindow cvMouseEvent:] in libopencv_highgui.a(window_cocoa.o)
      -[CVWindow rightMouseDragged:] in libopencv_highgui.a(window_cocoa.o)`

Comment: @lino I've updated the answer. You need to link with all frameworks/libs used by OpenCV because dependencies from static libraries are not inherited automatically.